# How to set Google Sheets tab color using switch case

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was able to change the color of a tab in Google Sheets using this code I found elsewhere:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    if (e.range.getA1Notation() != 'D1') return
    e.source.getActiveSheet()
        .setTabColor(e.value == 'Asphalt' ? 'red' : null)
}
```

However I would like to be able to actually change the tab color based on a range of options using Switch Case. Here is what I have so far but it is not working

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var trade = ss.getRange("D1")
  switch(trade){
    case "Asphalt":
        e.setTabColor("0000FF");
        break;
    case "Cabinetry":
        e.setTabColor("FF0000");
        break;
    default:
        e.setTabColor("008000");
}
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Please see [ask]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Spreadsheets API, but in your switch block, you are calling attempting to call a `setTabColor` function on the event parameter.  But your first example, the `setTabColor` is on whatever is returned by getActiveSheet. In other words, in your switch block, replace `e.setTabColor()` with `ss.setTabColor()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your very close, a few issues as follows:

```
var ss = e.SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
```

The `e` parameter returns an object containing various pieces of information about the edit event.

`e.source` returns the *Spreadsheet* object where the edit occurred. So, change to:

`var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();` To get the actual sheet where the edit occurred.

Now that `ss` is the active sheet `var trade = ss.getRange("D1")` will get that cell but you need to get the value from that cell. So, change to:

```
var trade = ss.getRange("D1").getValue(); To get the value in the cell.
```

In your switch block change the `e` to `ss`

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var trade = ss.getRange("D1").getValue();
  switch(trade){
    case "Asphalt":
        ss.setTabColor("0000FF");
        break;
    case "Cabinetry":
        ss.setTabColor("FF0000");
        break;
    default:
        ss.setTabColor("008000");
  }
}
```